# Mongoose - function inside .find method does not pass result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

How do I pass the result of the function successfully into .find method ? I want the argument passed via body-parser to be used as value for the key 'name' if user submitted a non-empty string. If user submitted an empty string, then empty object should be passed into .find method.

Function console.log works. If I submit an empty string then 'empty querydb' is printed to the console. Likewise, if I submit any other string then it gets printed out to the console correctly.

How can I pass the req.body.querydb as a value to 'name' key ?

HTML

```
 <form method="POST" action="form_query">
 <input type="textarea" name="querydb">
 <br><br>
 <button> Query </button>
 </form>
```

.JS

```
router.post('/form_query', function(req,res) {
someModel.find(function(err,results){
    if(!req.body.querydb){
        console.log("empty querydb")
        return {}
    } else {
        console.log(req.body.querydb)
        return {name:req.body.querydb}
    }
}).exec(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        send(err)
    } else {
        console.log('omg')
    }
```

Much thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose you have two possibilities to make a find request

- the `find(query, callback)` function
- the query builder

I recommand you to use the `find()` function. In your case, your code is like more this :

```
router.post('/form_query', function(req,res, next) {
    someModel.find({
        name : req.body.querydb
    }, function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            // request has an error like connection problem
            res({ error : err });
            return;
        }

        // request works correctly, you can send the users array for example
        res(users);
    });
});
```

The `find` function works like the mongodb pure `find()` function and, for me, it's the best way to make your requests.

EDIT :

It is advisable to control the incoming variables in the best way to perform this find.

For example, You can make this :

```
let findQuery = {};

if (req.body.querydb) {
    findQuery.name = req.body.querydb
}

someModel.find(findQuery, function (err, users) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: The idea here is right but I would check the input first to ensure it exists before the query to avoid an error, and perhaps validate it to ensure it is not going to return more than it should if there are any limitations on the system, something like req.body.querydb = {$exists: true} would return all data with a name which may not be acceptable in the system.

Comment: Normally the name param is escaped and, for that, the research is on `name : " {$exists: true} "`. But in your case, I recommand to test and modify the param before the `find()`

Comment: Thanks for the replies and sorry for getting back late. Not sure if this is what I was looking for, or perhaps I have not formulated it well enough. italic **"If user submitted an empty string, then empty object should be passed into .find method."** Reason why I'm doing an 'if' statement is because .find({name:req.body.name}) returns 0 results when user submits an empty form. Instead, I want API to return results as if .find({}) was executed and entire collection defined inside someModel was returned. Kindly let me know if clear. Not sure if I edit first post (?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are looking for but trying to understand as much as possible i am giving some code. This way you pass req.body.querydb as a value to 'name' key.

```
router.post('/form_query', function(req,res) {
someModel.find({name:req.body.querydb},function(err,results){
if(!req.body.querydb){
    console.log("empty querydb")
    return {}
} else {
    console.log(req.body.querydb)
    return {name:req.body.querydb}
}
}).exec(function(err, result) {
if (err) {
    send(err)
} else {
    console.log('omg')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are looking to pass a value from the api into a mongo query.

It might make sense to define the query outside of the actual call and then build it as needed or to ensure that a value is passed before getting to the query.

For example:

```
router.post('/form_query', function(req,res) {
    if(!req.body.querydb) {
        return res.status(404).send("empty querydb");
    }

    // validate querydb param

    someModel.find({ name: req.body.querydb }, function(err,results){
        if(!req.body.querydb){
            console.log("empty querydb")
            res.send
        } else {
            console.log(req.body.querydb)
            return res.status(200).send(results);
        }
    })
});
```

If you are using mongoose then the callback will be called after execution, and the query is the first param passed into the .find function.